# RESTEASY003325: Failed to construct public DocumentProvider in IntelliJ IDEA with updated dependencies in pom.xml

Tags: java, maven, intellij-idea, resteasy, java-17

I want to upgrade my maven project from java 11 to java 17 using a jdk17 etc.
I have changed multiple dependencies in my pom.xml and built and run the project in IntelliJ IDEA.
The project uses a RestEasy client to call different services.
My RestEasy version in the pom.xml is:

```
<resteasy.version>4.7.4.Final</resteasy.version>
```

Now I get the following error when running my code with IntelliJ IDEA:

```
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: RESTEASY003325: Failed to construct public org.jboss.resteasy.plugins.providers.DocumentProvider(org.jboss.resteasy.spi.ResteasyConfiguration)
    at org.jboss.resteasy.core.ConstructorInjectorImpl.constructOutsideRequest(ConstructorInjectorImpl.java:250)
    at org.jboss.resteasy.core.ConstructorInjectorImpl.construct(ConstructorInjectorImpl.java:209)
    at org.jboss.resteasy.core.providerfactory.Utils.createProviderInstance(Utils.java:102)
    at org.jboss.resteasy.core.providerfactory.CommonProviders.processProviderContracts(CommonProviders.java:87)
    ... 37 more
```

from the line:

```
 public static ResteasyProviderFactory RESTEASY_PROVIDER_FACTORY = new ResteasyProviderFactoryImpl() {{
        registerProvider(org.jboss.resteasy.plugins.providers.DataSourceProvider.class);
        registerProvider(org.jboss.resteasy.plugins.providers.DocumentProvider.class); // this line!
```

It did not happen without any changes in the pom. Does IntelliJ IDEA sometimes not really update everything properly? I use the right side maven tab and run clean and compile and sometimes "mvn clean compile -U" on the command line.

Comment: What container are you running in?

Comment: No container, just as a client!

Comment: Do you have a code snippet or example of how to reproduce it? I don't seem to be able to reproduce it.

Comment: Not really since the code is not Open Source. The issue seems to appear when the project is not properly build with the latest dependencies. I have changed versions of dependencies in the pom.xml and after doing a complete clean and rebuilding everything from scratch the issue seems to be gone.